# squid proxy server is refusing connections

Tags: proxy, squid

I am trying to make a squid proxy server accept connections from my ip-

For this I have added the following lines to the config file--

```
acl mynet src 122.179.44.192
acl use_ip myip 2604:c00:a:1:0:1:9074:9c80
```

The first line above refers to my PC (from which I want to use the proxy server), and the second is an IPv6 IP address for the proxy server itself.

To enable usage of the 2 ACL's as given above, the following lines have been added by me to the config file--

```
http_port 80
http_access allow mynet
http_access allow use_ip
```

But when I try to use the proxy server, it is refusing connections? Am i missing something here? What is wrong/missing in my config?

UPDATE- Output of this command--

```
netstat -lnp | grep squid
```

is given below--

```
tcp        0      0 :::3128                     :::*                        LISTEN      5285/(squid)
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:35556               0.0.0.0:*                               5285/(squid)
udp        0      0 :::40451                    :::*                                    5285/(squid)
```

Comment: How *exactly* are you trying to use the proxy server?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz - I am simply specifying the IPv6 IP address of the proxy server, in Proxy Server Settings for the Firefox web browser...

Comment: Under "HTTP proxy" or somewhere else? And what are you setting the port to?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Under HTTP Proxy, and port is 80

Comment: Well there's your problem. Your proxy is not listening on port 80 but on port 3128.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz - I changed the port in Firefox->Advanced Settings-> PRoxy to 3128, as well as 80, but still getting same error...pls help... thanks...

Answer (score 4):

I frequently find I've neglected to reconfigure the firewall.

Try 'service iptables stop' and then try again - it will probably work then.

*Don't forget to run 'service iptables start' again afterwards.*

If stopping the firewall temporarily fixed it, add a suitable line to your iptables config file (/etc/sysconfig/iptables on my centOS system).

Answer (score 2):

If you are getting the error "*proxy server is refusing connection*", then your proxy server may not be running.

If you are getting "*access denied*", then you need to check your acl.

Comment: Or it may not be listening on the IP address you are trying to connect.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: Yes, sure.

Comment: @Khaled i am getting "Proxy server is refusing connection" but when I log in to server via SSH and type in "service squid start" then I received a message "Starting Squid: OK"- even after that I am receiving the same error message- what am i missing here? Thanks...

Comment: @Arvind: Can you please post the output of `netstat -lnp | grep squid`? Also, post the IP your are requesting and how you are requesting locally or remotely.

Comment: @Khaled - the output of the command is now added to the question, I am requesting data from my local PC (IP=122.179.44.192) which tries to connect to the proxy server at IP= 2604:c00:a:1:0:1:9074:9c80